# Does adding a non-required suffix to numeric literals in calculations have any impact?

Tags: c#

With numeric literals used in calculations, does adding a suffix when it is not required have any performance impact whatsoever?

For example, given the following variable,

```
var decimalValue = 783.97m;
```

Is there any difference in performance between the following two statements?

```
var result = decimalValue / 12;

var result = decimalValue / 12m;
```

I would expect that the compiler is smart enough to treat the two statements the same way.

I realise that I could benchmark this and/or look at the compiled code but this is StackOverflow and someone will surely know more about this than I am likely to discover by poking around.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: You're storing the division of two decimals in both cases and the code generated is the same

Comment: "I could benchmark this and/or look at the compiled code" - why is "look at the language specification" not one of your options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, literals are hoisted to the relevant type in an expression if possible.

So:

```cs
int x = 7 / 3; // 2
decimal x = 7 / 3; // 2
decimal x = 7m / 3; // 2.33333...
```

You can use https://sharplab.io to see how the generated assembly looks like a for a certain piece of code in the future.